# SQL query does not execute in afterAll() function while writing test cases

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, protractor

I am writing unit test cases using Protractor, Jasmine.

I have a code written in beforeAll() functions which sets up data by fetching from database using sql queries

Similarly, there is an afterAll() function whose task is to reset the data in database as it was before the test cases executed

```
   beforeAll(() => {
     //get database connection

     // setup database data

   });



   it('should .....', () => {
    //code
   });



   afterAll(() => {
     // we can cleanup the database after we're done running our tests
     cleanup.clearAlerts(connection)
       .then(data => {
         //code
       });
   });
```

Here the beforeAll() functions executes sql queries correctly

However, the afterAll() function just doesn't execute any cleanup sql queries.

Comment: This is difficult to debug. Do you have logging in a `.catch` thrown errors for `cleanup.clearAlerts`? Could you provide your `cleanup` code and possibly show in your code where you are calling the `done` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Do some browser action in `afterall` to overcome the problem.

like

```
afterAll(async function () {
     //your sql query here
    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    await browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
});
```

Hope it help you.